# Error in openshift standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: no such file or directory

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, docker-image

I am running 90 microservices in openshift and few of the services are in `CrashLoopBackOff` and logs showing the following error message.

Error:

```
 OC logs -f : 
"standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: no such file or directory"
```

OC Describe:
Is there an issue with the image because describe output shows:

```
"Container image "IMAGE_TAG" already present on machine"
```

Comment: I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62745830/standard-init-linux-go219-exec-user-process-caused-no-such-file-or-directory) with similar error. Is it helpful for you? Additionally which version of Kubernetes did you used and how did you set up your cluster? Could you add some examples of implementation? Please [improve your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ```"Container image "IMAGE_TAG" already present on machine"``` is an unrelated information and just telling you, that the image you're trying to run already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that there is lack of information -
it is impossible to say exactly where the problem is.

I have found some similar errors.

---

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62745830/standard-init-linux-go219-exec-user-process-caused-no-such-file-or-directory) is one of the best solutions that matches description of your problem:

Here the key to solve the problem was replacing the aronautica crate via rust-argon2 and modifying the Dockerfile:

> ````rust
> FROM rust AS build
> WORKDIR /usr/src
> RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y build-essential git clang llvm-dev libclang-dev libssl-dev pkg-config libpq-dev brotli
> RUN USER=root cargo new loxe-api WORKDIR /usr/src/loxe-api COPY
> Cargo.toml Cargo.lock ./ COPY data ./data COPY migrations ./migrations
> RUN cargo build --release
> # Copy the source and build the application. COPY src ./src ENV PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS=1 ENV
> OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR="/usr/include/openssl" RUN cargo install --path .
>
> FROM debian:buster-slim COPY --from=build
> /usr/local/cargo/bin/loxe-api .
> # standard env COPY .env ./.env COPY data ./data COPY migrations ./migrations RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libssl-dev
> pkg-config libpq-dev brotli CMD ["/loxe-api"] ```
> ````

---

See also this similar issues:

- [second one](https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn/issues/663)
- [third one](https://discuss.redash.io/t/standard-init-linux-go-exec-user-process-caused-no-such-file-or-directory/7754)